# Typhoon can't be used after carthage build. 'TyphoonFactoryDefinition.h' file not found

Tags: ios, typhoon

I installed Typhoon into my swift project using Carthage. I drag and dropped the framework into my project and also added the required copy files script. Now if I reference Typhoon, I get an error that the

> could not build Objective-C module 'Typhoon'

and

> 'TyphoonFactoryDefinition.h' file not found

Did anybody else have this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem occurred over the last few days after an accidental change in Xcode Project configuration. It is our understanding that this issue has been fixed with Typhoon 3.2.3. Is this not the case for you?

**Edit:**

There was an additional file added the the Typhoon.h umbrella header that was not also exported. This has been corrected in v3.2.4 - thanks so much to [@akiraspeirs](https://github.com/akiraspeirs) for submitting the fix.

Comment: Yes, i'm using the latest version of typhoon and also carthage is updated to the latest version.

Comment: Oops - some XcodeProj config errors. Should be fixed in 3.2.4

Comment: Thanks @AlexMaie Apologies for that. We don't currently have framework target/carthage in our automated tests, but we should.

Comment: No problem. I'm happy that you are fast with the updates :)